# codesandbox compile error using Sass in React

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am testing a demo app in codesandbox and am getting the following error:

```
CompileError
Error: Error: ENOENT: No such file or directory., '/home'
        on line 7:9 of /stdin
>> @import "./home";

   --------^
```

Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-lehmann-yew2q

[image: Sass error]

I can fix the error by removing the underscore in import link to `@import "./_home";` but shouldn't this work without the underscore or is better to just add it?

Comment: This may actually be a bug in codesandbox. I found a [similar issue](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/4865#issuecomment-765802227) and have asked if this is also a bug.